# Wordpress shortcode return another php page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

My custom wordpress plugin shortcode is working when I just return something. But I want to return another php page, which includes html.

**This is my map.php**

```
<?php 
function example($map){
    echo "Hello!"; 
    }
?>
```

**I've tried like this**

```
add_shortcode( 'map_shortcode', 'map_shortcode' );
function map_shortcode() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'meyer-reset' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'tooltipster-bundle' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mypluginscript' );

    return $map;}
?>
```

**I mean the shortcode works; when I tried just a simple string like 'abc' it showed, so it works, but I want to show the other page on the return function.**

Comment: If you want to include your css/js files, I recommend you to include them in `functions.php` file using `wp_enqueue_scripts()` function.
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#default-scripts-included-and-registered-by-wordpress

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show an HTML view using WordPress shortcode, you can use `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` functions.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php

```
<?php
function map_shortcode() {

    ob_start();
    ?>  

    <!-- Your HTML codes here ...  -->

    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode("map_shortcode", "map_shortcode");
?>
```